# Under what conditions does Allah accept a jama'at prayer?

Tags: salat, jamaat

It is said that if you pray in Jama'at, Allah will accept your prayer so long as one person in the jama'at prayed a valid prayer.  But if nobody among the jama'at prayed a valid prayer, does Allah still accept it?

Comment: As written, your question was not particularly clear; I have taken the liberty to fix the grammar, please review to ensure that I have not actually missed the gist of your question.

Comment: I would also suggest you check out the advice in our help centre, particularly the page on "[How do I ask a good question?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)" for advice on how to better present your questions in the future.

Answer (score 0):

How will you come to know if no one or everyone prayed a valid prayer?

We all must try to offer valid prayers and hope Allah accepts OUR prayers.

May the creator guide us all.

Answer (score 0):

وعليكم السلام ورحمة الله وبركاته,

According to the Hanafis, there must be three people behind the Imam, and one of them must be a sane mature male. (According to Imam Abu Yusuf (rh)'s view, there must be two people, including one sane mature male)

According to the Malikis, the minimum number of followers is twelve local inhabitants of that particular locality excluding the Imam.

According to the Shafi'is and Hanbalis, there must be a minimum of forty followers upon whom Jumuah Salah is obligatory. Imam Ahmad R.A also has other views spanning from necessitating a minimum of 50 followers to only 3; however, a minimum of 40 seems to be the accepted view as stated in Al-Mughni of Ibn Qudama.

Source: https://islamqa.org/hanafi/askimam/2217

Comment: The question is asking about jama'a prayer while your answer is focussing on a specific jama'a prayer the jum'ah prayer.

Answer (score -1):

It's not your decision that who's pray would be accepted, so just try on yourself to have a good praying with most attention. Always think about God from the way of mercy and kindness. Praying in jamaat is so emphasized from different aspects. So what will accept or not is not our duty, you just try to be good, God will hold his duties.